# SignalR .NET Core camelCase JSON Contract Resolver

Tags: c#, json, signalr, asp.net-core

Using .NET Core RC2.  Got SignalR working, but trying to get it returning camelCase properties in JSON.

For APIs I'm using...

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o => {
    o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});
```

Maybe there's just nothing in place yet for SignalR (after all, it's not even supposed to work yet...), but wondering if anyone's figured it out yet?  I've tried a few things like...

```
services.AddTransient<IContractResolver, CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver>();
```

... but no go.

Anyone got this working yet?

Comment: Those questions and answers are for .net 4.5/4.6, not core.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/115) from the SignalR Core repository, there is no native way of doing this as of right now, but you can create a custom contract resolver as indicated in [this comment on an old SignalR issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/500#issuecomment-7453751).

Since that thread is for SignalR 2.2.0, let's make it work for SignalR Core.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Infrastructure;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

    public class SignalRContractResolver : IContractResolver
    {
        private readonly Assembly _assembly;
        private readonly IContractResolver _camelCaseContractResolver;
        private readonly IContractResolver _defaultContractSerializer;

        public SignalRContractResolver()
        {
            _defaultContractSerializer = new DefaultContractResolver();
            _camelCaseContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            _assembly = typeof(Connection).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        }


        public JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
        {
            if (type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Equals(_assembly))
                return _defaultContractSerializer.ResolveContract(type);

            return _camelCaseContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);
        }

    }
```

What happens here is that you cannot use the camel case contract resolver for the SignalR internals, because it would break the communication with the client.

So every time we resolve a contract in the `ResolveContract` method we have to check the assembly of the type currently resolved and check wether it is SignalR internal. If not, then we can resolve the contract using camel case.

At this point, we need to register this contract resolver in the framework.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new SignalRContractResolver();

        var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

        services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(JsonSerializer), 
                                           provider => serializer,
                                           ServiceLifetime.Transient));

        // register other services like SignalR, MVC and custom services
     }
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and works great.  Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I boiled down the registration to a one-liner: `services.AddSingleton(_ => new JsonSerializer { ContractResolver = new SignalRContractResolver() });` (and went with a singleton).

Answer (score 18):

Let me quote the answer of anurse on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/254):

Since the protocols are pluggable, the options were moved to a different location because you may choose not to use JSON at all. Now you set them in the .AddJsonProtocol extension method in ConfigureServices, like this:

```
services.AddSignalR()
.AddJsonProtocol(options => {
    // Edit or replace 'options.PayloadSerializerSettings' here!
});
```

Comment: this is actual for .net core 2.1 SignalR version. This should be accepted answer

Comment: Which would be this line:

options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

Answer (score 10):

As of the first final alpha release of signalR core (1.0.0-alpha1-final), you can get camel case like the code snippet below natively:

```
services.AddSignalR(option =>
{
    option.JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});
```

In fact, you can also employ any customized resolver instead of `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Arash.  Good to know.  I was using SignalR for a while, but after Azure dropped support for project.json, I implemented a simple .net core websocket server for my needs instead.  I may switch to SignalR when official .net core SignalR is released to avoid needing to maintain a custom implementation, but it's working well for now.

Comment: unfortunately this no longer works with 1.0.0-preview1-final

Answer (score 5):

In SignalR 3.0 you can do this with the following statement, as described in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

```cs
services.AddSignalR()
  .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(
    options =>
      options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and SignalR 3.0, this is what works:

```
services.AddSignalR()
   .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
   {
       options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; 
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

In .NET Core 3.0, using System.Text.Json

```
 services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options =>
        {
            options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        });
```