# Angular2-Get TypeScript - Object mapping

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning currently Angular2 and Typescript.
I got a good catch on the most of the basic-patterns, but one thing I don't get is the actual usage of the generic type on the observables and how the mapping is done. Probably I can show my example:
On the Server-side, I have a Controller returning some HelloWorld-Objects. This model has three simple properties and the method is looking like this:

```
    [HttpGet("helloWorlds")]
    public IEnumerable<HelloWorld> HelloWorlds()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new HelloWorld
            {
                GreetedPersons = 1,
                GreetingsDate = DateTime.Now,
                GreetingsMessage = "Greetings, traveller"
            },
            new HelloWorld
            {
                GreetedPersons = 1000,
                GreetingsDate = new DateTime(1986, 12, 29),
                GreetingsMessage = "Happy birthday"
            },
            new HelloWorld
            {
                GreetedPersons = 33333,
                GreetingsDate = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01),
                GreetingsMessage = "Happy new year"
            }
        };
    }
```

I have the same model on Tyepscript but with camel casing:

```
export class HelloWorld {
public greetingsMessage: string;

public greetingsDate: Date;

public greetedPersons: number;
}
```

To abstract the HTTP-Requests, I created a generic Http-Service on Typescript:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
constructor(private http: Http) { }

public get<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return this.processResponse(this.http.get(url));
}

public post<T>(url: string, body: any, contentType: http.ContentType): Promise<T> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', this.mapContentType(contentType));

    var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });

    return this.processResponse(this.http.post(url, body, requestoptions));
}

private processResponse<T>(response: Observable<Response>): Promise<T> {
    return response.map(this.extractJson)
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private mapContentType(contentType: http.ContentType) : string {
    switch (contentType) {
        case http.ContentType.ApplicationJson:
            return "application/json";
        default:
            throw new RangeError(contentType.toString() + " is not recognized");
    }
}

private extractJson(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    debugger;
    return body;
}

private extractArray(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    // Low Level technical logging
    // We pass the error via promise to give the client the possibility to show a nice message
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);
    return Promise.reject(errMsg);
}
}
```

And finally, my HelloWorld-Service can then request the HelloWorld:

```
getHelloWorlds(): Promise<HelloWorld[]> {
    const url = "api/HelloWorld/helloWorlds";
    return this.httpService.get<HelloWorld[]>(url);
}
```

What I don't get: In the JSON, I do already receive the HelloWorld-Properties with camel casing, so everything works!
"Um, everything works, why does he even bother?" Good question, because at the moment I'd like to implement a generic SignalR-Service, using this Tutorial: https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular2-and-signalr-part-1/

It works also, but the camel casing doesn't get applied via some magic, so this model

```
export class ChannelEvent {
name: string;
channelName: string;
timestamp: Date;
data: any;
json: string;

constructor() {
    this.timestamp = new Date();
}
}
```

Doesn't work, I need to define it as pascal cased.

I found some possibilities to map one TypeScript to another, but none of the tutorials I've seen so far, did say anything about this matter.

Comment: Have you considered a JSON contract resolver that would transform the SignalR responses to PascalCase? Something along these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832165/signalr-net-core-camelcase-json-contract-resolver

Comment: Hm, interesting approach. My problem is basically the fact, that I don't know how is it done via the HTTP and if and where I should do it at all.